# Using $.ajax to fetch static html files in phonegap and Windows Phone 7

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-7, cordova, requirejs

We're using Phonegap/Cordova 2.3.0 to deploy an app to Windows Phone 7. The application uses Require.js to dynamically load all modules. One module is called 'router' and is responsible for fetching static html from local files and loading their contents into a `<div>`. This works on iPhone, iPad, and Windows Phone 8. But there's something strange happening in WP7.

Sample code from `router.js`:

```
//path that works with WP8
var path = "www/views/";
$.ajax({ url: path + "test3.html" })
                .done(function(html) {
                    alert(html); //result from Windows Phone 8
                }).fail(function(error) {
                    alert(error); //result from Windows Phone 7
                });
```

The error that's given when testing on WP7 is a 404 Not Found.

I say "there's something strange happening" because I can copy the exact code above to the `main.js` (require.js entry point) or the `index.html` and it will run without error. But when I put that code in my `router.js`, it returns the error.

Some observations:

- `router.js` is in the same folder (`/www/js`) as `main.js`.
- `index.html` is in the `/www` folder.
- I've tried about every path combination I could think of hoping to stumble across one that worked. `/app/www/views`, `app/www/views`, `/www/views`, `www/views`, `/views`, `views`, and even `x-wmapp0:/app/www/views` and `x-wmapp1:/app/www/views`.
- Obviously, I have provided a super simplified example. If you need more, just tell me.

Comment: I can take a look if you share sample code. I would recommend to 1)Check that the static page exists in CordovaSourceDictionary.xml 2)try to place your static page in the same folder as index.html and use 'test3.html' as a path (w/o app/www)

Comment: the `CordovaSourceDictionary.xml` seems to be updating properly on build. The files are definitely listed (albeit with `www/` prepended). I tried what you suggested and moved the `test.html` files to the `www/` folder with the index, but got the same 404. http://bit.ly/112lDNU

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following may help you to understand the problem

1) Access to local files on Cordova WP7 is done via File.cs (\templates\standalone\cordovalib\Commands\File.cs).readAsText method. So you can attach full cordovalib instead of compiled dll and see where Cordova tries to find that file.

2) Translation between ajax requests and local files is done at XHRPatch (cordova-2.3.0.js) so try adding uri tracing somewhere [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-wp7/blob/master/example/www/cordova-2.4.0.js#L5827)  (console.log(uri);)

Comment: This was really helpful. I put a breakpoint in `File.cs` and it only hits it once, when I load from the js code in index. It doesn't break when the js code in router tries to load the file. Interesting. Then I tried your suggestion about putting `console.log(uri)` in the cordova.js code that opens the XHR request. Also interesting. When it opens the file from the index, the uri is `test1.html`. When it attempts to open from other areas, it's `test1.html?_=543456543`. That might be it. I'm testing it out.

Comment: Bingo! I'll post the actual problem here for posterity. The problem was that jQuery was configured globally to NOT cache ajax requests (`{cache: false}`). So, it was appending _=65432345 (timestamp) to all requests to override server caching. That works great for web URLS, but not for loading a file from the file system in WP7.

Answer (score 0):

With Cordova 2.7.0 that I am using now (on Windows Phone 8 - on WP7 it may differ!) it looks like you just have to eference with a path relative to the root of your application (not your `www` directory! That means you must go from `www/path/to/my/file.js`

Hope that helps - it was confusing for me!